# How to return field as set() using peewee

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, orm, peewee

I have currently worked abit with ORM using Peewee and I have been trying to understand how I am able to get the field `url` from the table. The condition is that column `visible` needs to be true as well. Meaning that if `visible` is True and the `store_id` is `4` then return all the `url` as set.

I have currently done something like this

```
from peewee import (
    Model,
    TextField,
    BooleanField
)
from playhouse.pool import PooledPostgresqlDatabase

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Connection to Postgresql
# -------------------------------------------------------------------------
postgres_pool = PooledPostgresqlDatabase(
    'xxxxxxx',
    host='xxxxxxxx',
    user='xxxxxxxx',
    password='xxxxxx',
    max_connections=20,
    stale_timeout=30,
)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- #

class Products(Model):
    store_id = TextField(column_name='store_id')
    url = TextField(column_name='url')
    visible = BooleanField(column_name='visible')

    class Meta:
        database = postgres_pool
        db_table = "develop"

    @classmethod
    def get_urls(cls):
        try:
            return set([i.url for i in cls.select().where((cls.store_id == 4) & (cls.visible))])
        except Products.IntegrityError:
            return None
```

However using the method takes around 0.13s which feels abit too long for me than what it supposed to do which I believe is due to the for loop and needing to put it as a `set()` and I wonder if there is a possibility that peewee can do something like `cls.select(cls.url).where((cls.store_id == 4) & (cls.visible)` and return as set()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many products do you have? How big is this set? Why not use `distinct()` so that the database de-duplicates them for you? What indexes do you have? All of these questions are much more pertinent than "how do I make this python loop faster".

I'd suggest that you need an index on `store_id, visible` or `store_id where visible`.

```
create index "product_urls" on "products" ("store_id") where "visible"
```

You could even use a covering index but this may take up a lot of disk space:

```
create index "product_urls" on "products" ("store_id", "url") where visible
```

Once you've got the actual query sped up with an index, you can also use `distinct()` to make the db de-dupe the URLs before sending them to Python. Additionally, since you only need the URL, just select that column and use the `tuples()` method to avoid creating a class:

```
@classmethod
def get_urls(cls):
    query = cls.select(cls.url).where((cls.store_id == 4) & cls.visible)
    return set(url for url, in query.distinct().tuples())
```

Lastly please read the docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#iterating-over-large-result-sets

Comment: Appreciate this answer and I almost lost my hope regardng this question and I am happy to add up some more information - I have around 2500 products and this is how I created the database: `https://hastebin.com/ifujawedad.sql` - In there you can see the index and also that there is no chance of duplicate URL since I have set it up as UNIQUE. I used to do before `return set(i.url for i in cls.select(cls.url).where((cls.store_id == store_id) & cls.visible))` but I am not sure if its good enough compare to yours and I am not sure if I would need to create an idex for it